# c# restart a tcp server

Tags: c#, multithreading

I have the following c# form application which is a tcp server which handles incoming file request. I would like to restart the thread when there is some exception handling or via manual button press. The problem is that once i invoke the thread Abort() function, the whole application freezes.

I do understand there are other methods in doing this more gracefully. How do I do then? Thanks!

```
  public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Thread t2;

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
         t2 = new Thread(delegate()
        {
            startServer();
        });
        t2.Start();

    }

    private void restartServer()
    {
        t2.Abort();
        t2.Start();
    }

    private void startServer()
    {

            // Listen on port 1234      
        TcpListener tcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 1234);

            tcpListener.Start();

            Console.WriteLine("Server started");
            textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => textBox1.Text += "server started"));
            //Infinite loop to connect to new clients      
            while (true)
            {
                // Accept a TcpClient      
                TcpClient tcpClient = tcpListener.AcceptTcpClient();

                //textBox1.Text += "Connected to client\n";
                textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => textBox1.Text += "Connected to client"));
                StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(tcpClient.GetStream());

                // The first message from the client is the file size      
                string cmdFileSize = reader.ReadLine();

                // The first message from the client is the filename      
                string cmdFileName = reader.ReadLine();

                int length = Convert.ToInt32(cmdFileSize);
                byte[] buffer = new byte[length];
                int received = 0;
                int read = 0;
                int size = 1024;
                int remaining = 0;

                // Read bytes from the client using the length sent from the client      
                while (received < length)
                {
                    remaining = length - received;
                    if (remaining < size)
                    {
                        size = remaining;
                    }

                    read = tcpClient.GetStream().Read(buffer, received, size);
                    received += read;
                }

                // Save the file using the filename sent by the client      
                String fileName = Path.GetFileName(cmdFileName);
                String path1 = Path.GetDirectoryName(Application.ExecutablePath) + "\\ReceivedLogs\\" + fileName;
                Console.WriteLine("path:"+path1);
                using (FileStream fStream = new FileStream(path1, FileMode.Create))
                {
                    fStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                    fStream.Flush();
                    fStream.Close();
                }
                textBox1.Invoke((MethodInvoker)(() => textBox1.Text += "File received and saved in " + Environment.CurrentDirectory + "\n"));
               // textBox1.Text += ("File received and saved in " + Environment.CurrentDirectory+"\n");
            }
        }

    private void label1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        restartServer();
    }


    }
}
```

**Edit 1**:Changed all invoke to 'BeginInvoke' and the freeze still persist.

Comment: Change `textBox1.Invoke` to `textBox1.BeginInvoke`.  Should try to avoid using the former from worker threads due to the probability of the application freezing

Comment: Hi @MickyDuncan, i changed to beginInvoke but it still freezes.

Comment: Freeze? I would think having an unhandled thread and aborting it would crash the whole app. Try adding a try catch for your new thread and handle any possible exceptions and swallow ThreadAbortException.

Comment: Also Thread.Abort might freeze in certain situations: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20520689/thread-abort-method-freezes which will make your app freeze, but when it no longer freezes my previous comment comes into action.

Comment: `Thread.Abort()` is perhaps naughty. Consider using a `ManualResetEvent` and change your `while(true)` to `while(! _event.WaitOne(0))`. The latter is more graceful and nicer to puppies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Wolf5 and his link, [Thread.Abort() method freezes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20520689/thread-abort-method-freezes). By stopping all services in the thread and creating boolean works.

```
    private void restartServer()
    {
      try { 
        try {
            check = false;
            tcpListener.Stop();
            textBox1.BeginInvoke((MethodInvoker)(() => textBox1.AppendText("Server stopping..\r\n")));
            t2.Abort();
            check = true;
            startThread();
        }
        catch(ThreadAbortException){

        }
         }  
        catch(ThreadAbortException)
      {
          Thread.ResetAbort();
      }
    }
```

So the point is to let the CLR know that **it is safe to abort by stopping all running services** before aborting. Thanks! :D

Comment: The ThreadAbortException is needed where you have the loop. When that thread gets the Abort signal IT throws a ThreadAbortException. So move the try catch to startServer().

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcplistener.stop%28v=vs.110%29.aspx  

i would call tcpListener.Stop() catch the SocketException and flag the while statement  while(_isListening) {  
}